# formatting linux command output in php

Tags: php, linux, formatting

I have the following script which does what I want

```
<?php
$data = array();                // define array

exec('faxstat -s', $data, $ret);     // execute command, output is array
echo "<pre>";

if ($ret == 0) {                // check status code. if successful
    foreach ($data  as $line)  {  // process array line by line
    echo "$line \n";

    }
} else {
    echo "Error in command";    // if unsuccessful display error
}

echo "</pre>";
?>
```

FAXSTAT is a command used in hylafax for monitoring channel status.

Sample output is as follows:

```
Modem ttyIAX017 (+1.999.555.1212): Running and idle 
Modem ttyIAX018 (+1.999.555.1212): Running and idle 
Modem ttyIAX019 (+1.999.555.1212): Running and idle 
Modem ttyIAX020 (+1.999.555.1212): Running and idle 
Modem ttyIAX021 (+1.999.555.1212): Running and idle
```

Now I want to modify `Modem ttyIAX017 (+1.999.555.1212)` with Channel 17.
I want to do the same for all the channels with respective channel number. Is there a way to do this.

I have searched a lot on google but could not find anything relevant.

Please help.

Comment: Can you provide example of your expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line which says

```
echo "$line \n";
```

to

```
echo "Channel ".substr($line, 13, 2)." ".substr($line, 33);
```

**How does this work?**

substr($line, 13, 2) calculates the two digits to print after "Channel" and substr($line, 33) hides the part of string we don't want to print.

You may want to change the number 13, 2 and 33 if need arises.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you and your solution works. 
I just had to modify the script to show one channel per line as below:

```
echo "Channel ".substr($line, 12, 3)." ".substr($line, 33)." \n";
```

Also is there a way to skip First Line and use the code given by you for the rest of the lines.
Example: Normal Output would be:

```
HylaFAX scheduler on Server.domain.pvt: Running
Modem boston18 (+1.999.555.1212): Running and idle
Modem boston10 (+1.999.555.1212): Running and idle
```

Preferred output should be:

```
HylaFAX scheduler on Server.domain.pvt: Running
Channel 01: Running and idle
Channel 02: Running and idle
Channel 03: Running and idle
```

If possible i would like to skip the first line and show remaining channel info one per line.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into php manual and found what i want.
I have skipped the first line in the array by adding the below code:

```
    if(!isset($flag_first)) { //skip first line from array
    $flag_first=1;
    continue;}
```

echo "Channel ".substr($line, 12, 3)." ".substr($line, 33)." \n";

Thank you sp2hari for your help.